# .Net MVC 4 Ajax Form Validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, ajax.beginform

I´m having a problem with a ajax form validation (as I´ve seen many people have, but after hours of searching, I still haven´t found a proper answer).

The AJAX-post is ok, and I get the response I want, but two things are not working as planned:

1. The client-side validation doesn´t work.
2. My Forms DataType(DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)), doesn´t work (type="text" is attribute of my , not type="email").

I have included the following in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Static/js/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Static/js/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
```

My form model is:

```
public class EventForm 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name must be filled")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false,ErrorMessage = "Last Name must be filled")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email must be filled")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Compare("Email",ErrorMessage = "Email adress do not match")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Phone number must be filled")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Company Name must be filled")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Adress must be filled")]
    public string Adress { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Zip must be filled")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Postal city must be filled")]
    public string PostalCity { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

And my view contains this form:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
        {

            <div id="result"></div>

            {
                Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
            }
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p=>p.EventForm)
            @Html.EditorFor(p=>p.EventForm)
        }
```

And finally, my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(EventPage currentPage)
    {
        var model = new EventViewModel()
            {
                CurrentPage = currentPage,
                EventForm = new EventForm()
            };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Index(EventViewModel form)
    {
        return PartialView("PagePartial/FormSubmit", form.EventForm);
    }
```

Help?

Comment: "I have included the following in the `<head>`" , why are you not using a script bundle?

Comment: That will come later- we fix that in the later stages of our project. These are only added in the head for now to test.